Choice of oscillator for microcontroller
I'm using STM32F103C8 and I read Oscillator Design guide and one of the part numbers of recommended 8 MHz crystals is this one:

-------------------------------------------------------------  1  ------------------------------------------------
I have to choose C1, C2 (at the ends of the oscillator) and Rext in the pcb.
From the picture above, with Cstray = 4pF:
\begin{equation}
C_{load} = 20pF = \frac{C1*C2}{C1+C2} + C_{stray}
--> C_{load} = 16pF = \frac{C1 \cdot C2}{C1 + C2} \\
C1 = 32pF \\
C2 = 32pF
\end{equation}
I can now calculate \begin{equation} R_{ext} = \frac{1}{2\pi f C_{2}} = 621 \Omega \end{equation}
The problem is that 32pF > from the range [5..25]pF specified in [STM32F103C8 datasheet]
3:

Did I calculate something wrong?
-------------------------------------------------------------  2  ------------------------------------------------------
If the previous calculation is correct, I need to calculate the gain margin to verify Eric Vittoz's condition (gain margin > 5):
\begin{equation}
 \text{gain margin} = \frac{gm}{gm_{crit}} = 5.164  \\
 gm = 25 \text{ mV/A (in the STM32F103C8 datasheet) }  \\
 gm_{crit} = 4 \times (ESR + R_{ext}) \times (2 \pi f)^2 \times (C_o + C_l)^2 = 5.16 \times 10^{-12} \\
\end{equation}
The result is very close to 5!! Will the oscillator start oscillating or should I change something?

The quote you've highlighted also reads: "10pF can be used as a rough estimate of the combined pin and board capacitance", whereas you've only used 4pF as Cstray in your calculation.

Does your project require an external oscillator? I have seen a lot of people who struggled with quarz oscillators, but most of the projects could be done with the internal oscillator. The accuracy of the HSI RC oscillators is most times under 2%.

FOX's quoted ESR is a maximum value, and startup $g_m$ is a minimum - so your gain margin is OK.

Oscillator or crystal? Does it have 4 pins or 2?

Is a crystal, it has two pins. I confused between "crystal" and "oscillator"@glen_geek

Your calculations are correct.
Also you are not choosing an oscillator, you are choosing a crystal. You kind of chose the oscillator because it is in the chip you will design with.
With that crystal, you end up with load capacitors that are higher than the recommended 25pF values for this MCU.
It may be suitable for some other STM32 than the F103 but not for F103.
So if you work backwards, using highest capacitors of 25pF, and even assuming ideal case of no stray capacitance, it means you can have a crystal with load requirement up to 12.5pF - and add the amount of stray which may be much below 5pF, so in practice a 16pF crystal might already be too high.
Also for same reason you end up with margin of 5. 5 is usually good enough but by selecting some other crystal you can improve the margin.

thanks for the reply. Doing the calculations again using C1=C2=25pF and Cstray = 5pF the gain margin is 4.7 .. too low. Maybe better to change crystal or choose to use an oscillator. How do you quantify Cstray ?? (I have never done hardware design).

@toby514 If you got less margin with smaller cap values, you might have an error in your calculations. See how the capacitance is squared? Cstray you can simulate, estimate or test. Buy a suitable crystal and suitable caps based on rough guess, if measured frequency is off due to wrong load, you change the caps to bring the frequency to nominal. However, for a one-off hobby project, it might be irrelevant if you buy a 100ppm crystal and you have 10ppm extra error from wrong caps. Although some interfaces like Ethernet require some specific tight ppm over all conditions so be careful.

thank you very much!
